# @ModelAttribute declaration at a method level in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

The problem I am facing is if I at all define @ModelAttribute at a method level like

```
  @ModelAttribute("addresses")
 public List<Address> getAllAddresses() {
  // Delegate to service
  return addressService.getAll();
 }
```

then would I get all the addresses as a list object in my JSP readily and I can iterate over them? Something like

```
 <c:forEach items="${addresses}" var="address">
  <tr>
   <td><c:out value="${address.id}" /></td>
   <td><c:out value="${address.street}" /></td>
   <td><c:out value="${address.city}" /></td>
   <td><c:out value="${address.zipCode}" /></td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Or still have I to add it as an attribute something like

```
model.addAttrbute
```

?

I am not clearly understanding the scenario. Being a beginner I am finding this topic very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

No,  @ModelAttribute("addresses") is enough for your purpose, it will implicitly add the attributes in model.

From Spring doc:-

```
@ModelAttribute
public Account addAccount(@RequestParam String number) {
    return accountManager.findAccount(number);
}
```

> @ModelAttribute: adds an attribute implicitly by returning it.

You can read the spring doc here : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods

Comment: So all I need to have extra to this snippet of code is addresses.java domain model java class ?

Comment: No, you don't need to create addresses.java.